# Python output pie chart preceded by tuple

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

When I run the following in an IPython notebook:

```
plt.pyplot.pie(res3,shadow=True,labels=lab,autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

I get the following in front of my pie chart:

```
([<matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x10cd78610>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x10cd74910>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x10cd72c10>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x10cd6ff10>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x10cd68250>,
  <matplotlib.patches.Wedge at 0x10cd66550>],
 [<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd78f90>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd72350>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd6f650>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd6c950>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd68c50>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd66f50>],
 [<matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd744d0>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd727d0>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd6fad0>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd6cdd0>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cd66110>,
  <matplotlib.text.Text at 0x10cf29410>])
```

I want to get just the pie chart. How do I do this?

Comment: Well that is the data that makes up the pie chart. So what exactly do you want? An image of the pie chart? A window displaying the pie chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not going to change what `pyplot.pie` returns, just catch the return value in a variable which you don't use like:

```
_ = plt.pyplot.pie(res3,shadow=True,labels=lab,autopct='%1.1f%%')
```

---

I tried around a bit with the IPython Notebook, and running `plt.show()` in the same cell also works, because the notebook outputs only the return value of the last line in the cell.